# On the convergence of a series involving the Riemann Zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

I've used the formula that tell us **Murty** from [1] in a special case to do calculations in the following

> **Example.** I take the special case in page 211 of [1], taking the specialization $T=1/k$, where $k\geq 2$ is an integer, after I multiply the identity by $\mu(k)/k$, where $\mu(m)$ is the Möbius function, and taking the sum over all integers $k\geq 2$ one has 
>   $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)}{k}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(n+1)^2}{k^n}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\mu(k)\frac{k(k+1)}{(k-1)^3}-4\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)}{k^2}-\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)}{k}.$$
>   Using the Dirichlet series $1/\zeta(s)$ for $\Re s>1$ where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann Zeta function, and the Prime Number Theorem one has by means of absolute convergence
>   $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty(n+1)^2\left(\frac{1}{\zeta(n+1)}-1\right)=5-\frac{4}{\zeta(2)}+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{\mu(k)k(k+1)}{(k-1)^3}.$$

I know that this example makes sense if one can justify the convergence of some of previous series.

When I returned to the main identity, first paragraph in page 211 of [1], and did previous tricks for the specilization $$T=\frac{1}{k^{\epsilon}},$$ for integers $k\geq 2$ and $\epsilon>\frac{1}{2}$ a real number (I believe that I can take here $z$ instead of $\epsilon$, as a complex number with $\Re z>\frac{1}{2}$, but I don't understand well the nature of the series in RHS) then I wrote as the series in LHS of my identity, that is the basis of my

> **Question.** Justify the convergence of the series 
>   $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left( \left(\sum_{j=0}^n\alpha^{n-j}\beta^j\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\gamma^{n-j}\delta^j\right)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{\zeta(\epsilon n+1)}-1\right) \right)$$
>   when $\epsilon>\frac{1}{2}$ is a real number (or tell us your extension for  complex numbers, writing $z$ instead our previous $\epsilon$)?  **Many thanks.**

---

[1] Ram Murty, *Problems in Analytic Number Theory,* Second Edition, Graduate Text in Mathematics 206, Springer (2008).

Comment: 1) I belive that the convergence of the series in LHS of the Example is justified by means of the comparison test.  2) I believe that the nature of the parameters $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $\delta$ are real numbers. 3) What I am asking is if you can add your mathematics here to get, your proposition showing the convergence in the general case, that is the Question (also I wrote the similar RHS for Question following my tricks, and the series involving the MÖbius function in RHS seem difficult).  Manyt thanks.

Comment: Instead of saying thank you and deleting what I wrote, can you use it for answering **rigorously** to your question ?

Comment: Since 4 months I'm trying to explain to you what it means making some maths : writing a proof, the opposite of playing with formulas you don't understand.

Comment: You can help here, answer the question, then in a next future I can improve @user1952009 And I don't know how solve the Question, I don't able to provide us a proof, thanks.

Comment: That's my problem : when we give all the hints or even a complete answer, you can't use it for writing a full proof. It clearly means this is not of your level, and that you should forget about $\zeta(s)$ and work on traditional $\int$ and $\sum$. For example [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sequences-and-series)  those 20000 questions interesting for you.

Comment: If you want provide me an answer, you are welcome. My attempt was write an example and ask myself the generalization. Can you say something about the generalization @user1952009 ? Then I will learn from your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Recopier des formules que tu ne comprends pas ce n'est pas faire des maths. Es-tu capable de faire des maths ?

Comment: I did simple reasonings combining the formulas in this exercise with summation, and PNT to get previous statement in my Example. I believe that  you didn't know it, before today. After I've created the Question as a generalization of previous. If do you know how to prove/study in what cases is convergent you are very welcome to add your answer. Thanks @user1952009

Comment: Adding a bounty will not help you reduce the gap between your ambitions (tackling elaborate results from analytic number theory) and your abilities. @user1952009 tried all they could to explain this point to you but you simply refused to listen (and added some semi-insulting considerations to ice the cake). Too bad.

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback @Did My only purpose is learn more, and if today I was wrong, or tomorrow, then I am saying I'm sorry. Thanks to you and user1952009 for your attention.

Comment: @user1952009 I don't want to bother you as past year. I am sorry when I lose your knowledge and advices. Many thanks for your mathematics and if there were some of my attitudes or words that you don't like, sorry me.

Comment: Si tu veux arrêter de te moquer du monde, alors commence par poser des questions de ton niveau, c'est à dire pour lesquelles, lorsqu'on te donne toutes les étapes, tu es capable d'écrire la démonstration complète / détaillée et rigoureuse. Par exemple, si tu parles de $\zeta(s)$, alors tu dois savoir montrer : que $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}$ converge et est analytique pour $Re(s) > 1$, et que cette série admet un prolongement analytique à $Re(s) > 0, s \ne 1$ et à $s \in \mathbb{C}, s \ne 1$, ou encore que $-\log(1-p^{-s}) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{p^{-sk}}{k}$

Comment: Pour le moment, tu n'as pas été capable de formuler une seule démonstration mathématique, c'est à dire que les réponses et les commentaires qu'on te donne ne servent à rien, surtout que personne d'autre ne tombera sur tes questions qui sont dans leur immense majorité soit triviales, soit déconnectées des démonstrations que les gens recherchent en lien avec $\zeta(s)$.

Comment: Can I interrupt the brouhah in French to ask what are these constants $\alpha,\beta, \gamma,\delta?$

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your attention @zhw. are real numbers in the formula from Murty's book. The I am asking for which constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ and $\delta$ one has that our series is convergent.

Comment: OK, but your question doesn't read that way. It says "justify the convergence".

Comment: It is true, I am asking to discuss the convergence of the series with such real constants, if some user knows that the series is convergent indepently of the value of such constants then he/she can add the reasoning. Many thanks @zhw. (On the other hand with respect comments in other language, I take these words and mathematics in comments as very valuable, not as a *brouhah*.)

Comment: I mispelled it, it's "brouhaha". There's a bit of brouhaha going on above, they can be fun actually, and  yes, one can learn from it.

Comment: You take these observations as very valuable, you say? This seems mainly a polite way to say that you do not care at all and that you will not change your attitude by even one iota. *Comme le fait remarquer @user1952009, cela équivaut purement et simplement à se moquer du monde.* Your call, but do not complain afterwards, right?

Comment: @Did Yes are valuable. With respect to people that know a lot of mathematics and having I currently no good abilities, maybe there is a controversy stated, I say that  my failure versus the ability of this people, when try help me. I believe that could be reflect something of my previous words in my attitude. But I don't like the kind of mathematics that I try, in the past I've studied mathematics and I know to reconigze good mathematics, But I admire to users that know a lot of mathematics, is my dream, only that if I am frustrated maybe I reflect frustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lemma**: Upper bound on $\zeta\left(1+x\right)$:

$$\zeta \left(1+x\right) = \frac{1}{1^{1+x}}+\frac{1}{2^{1+x}}+\frac{1}{3^{1+x}}+\frac{1}{4^{1+\frac{1}{x}}}+\frac{1}{5^{1+x}}+\cdots< \\ \frac{1}{1^{1+x}}+\frac{1}{2^{1+x}}+\frac{1}{2^{1+x}}+\frac{1}{4^{1+x}}+\frac{1}{4^{1+x}}+\cdots = \\ 1+\frac{2}{2^{1+x}}+\frac{4}{4^{1+x}}+\frac{8}{8^{1+x}}+\cdots = \\ 1+\frac{1}{2^{x}}+\frac{1}{4^{x}}+\frac{1}{8^{x}}+\cdots= \\ (2^{-x})^0+(2^{-x})^1+(2^{-x})^2+(2^{-x})^3+\cdots = \\ \frac{1}{1-2^{-x}}$$

This gives $\zeta \left(1+\varepsilon n\right) <\frac{1}{1-2^{-\varepsilon n}}$, so $\frac{1}{\zeta \left(1+\varepsilon n\right)} > 1-2^{-\varepsilon n}$, so $0 > \frac{1}{\zeta \left(1+\varepsilon n\right)}-1 > -2^{-\varepsilon n}$.

Because it is easier to deal with positive numbers, rewrite to $$0 < 1-\frac{1}{\zeta \left(1+\varepsilon n\right)} < 2^{-\varepsilon n}$$

**Lemma:** Now, we have $\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\alpha^{n-j}\beta^j\right) < \left(\sum_{j=0}^n\max\{\alpha,\beta\}^n\right) = (n+1)\max\{\alpha,\beta\}^n$. Similiar, $\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\gamma^{n-j}\delta^j\right) < \left(\sum_{j=0}^n\max\{\gamma,\delta\}^n\right) = (n+1)\max\{\gamma,\delta\}^n$. So if $$\max\{\alpha,\beta\}\max\{\gamma,\delta\}2^{-\varepsilon} < 1,$$

we can deduce that

$$0 < \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left( \left(\sum_{j=0}^n\alpha^{n-j}\beta^j\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\gamma^{n-j}\delta^j\right)\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{\zeta(\epsilon n+1)}\right) \right) < \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left( \max\{\alpha,\beta\}\max\{\gamma,\delta\}2^{-\varepsilon}  \right)^n (n+1)^2 = \sum_{n=2}^\infty c^n(n+1)^2 $$

with $c<1$. Now let $c_n=c^n(n+1)^2$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n} =\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{c^{n+1}(n+2)^2}{c^n(n+1)^2} =c<1$, so by the ratio test it converges.

---

It can also be shown that if $\max\{\alpha,\beta\}\max\{\gamma,\delta\}2^{-\varepsilon} \geq 1$ the series diverge.

$$\zeta(1+x) > 1+ \frac{1}{2^{1+x}} =  \frac{2^{1+x}+1}{2^{1+x}} $$

Therefore, $1-\frac{1}{\zeta(1+x)}>\frac{1}{2^{1+x}+1} > \frac{1}{2^{2+x}}$.

Therefore, $1-\frac{1}{\zeta(1+\varepsilon n)}>\frac{1}{2^{1+\varepsilon n}+1} > \frac{1}{2^{2+\varepsilon n}} = \frac14 2^{-\varepsilon n}$.

We can deduce that: $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left( \left(\sum_{j=0}^n\alpha^{n-j}\beta^j\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^n\gamma^{n-j}\delta^j\right)\cdot\left(1-\frac{1}{\zeta(\epsilon n+1)}\right) \right) > \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left( \max\{\alpha,\beta\}\max\{\gamma,\delta\}2^{-\varepsilon}  \right)^n \cdot \frac14 $$

which clearly diverges.

Comment: Many thaks for your answer and attention, are very nice all your deductions. I will study it.